# Python 3 - CSV File Issue (ValueError: not enough values to unpack)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, writer

I tried modifying this [example code](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SimplePrograms) on python 3.x.

```
import csv

def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)

# write stocks data as comma-separated values
f = open('stocks.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows([
    ('GOOG', 'Google, Inc.', 505.24, 0.47, 0.09),
    ('YHOO', 'Yahoo!, Inc.', 27.38, 0.33, 1.22),
    ('CNET', 'CNET Networks, Inc.', 8.62, -0.13, -1.49)
])

f.close()

# read stocks data, print status messages
f = open('stocks.csv', 'r')
stocks = csv.reader(f)
status_labels = {-1: 'down', 0: 'unchanged', 1: 'up'}
for ticker, name, price, change, pct in stocks:
    status = status_labels[cmp(float(change), 0.0)]
    print('%s is %s (%s%%)' % (name, status, pct))

f.close()
```

With suggestions from @glibdud, and @bernie, I have updated my code.
Am getting the below error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 0)

What am I missing?

**Note:** *Removed my question about double quotes in CSV file for string. Double quotes will be there if we have comma separated string, otherwise not.*

Comment: You're probably not getting any output because you didn't close the file after writing and before reading.

Comment: `Yahoo! Inc.` is not quoted because it doesn't have a comma in it.

Comment: Thanks @bernie got it. Why am I getting the not enough values to unpack error?

Comment: I ran your code and didn't get that error.

Comment: @bernie, I guess I found the root cause. While creating the rows it creates some empty lines also, that's the reason it is not getting read. Do you know how can I avoid empty lines?

Comment: Try this: `f = open('stocks.csv', 'w', newline='')`

Answer (score 1):

The Problem occurs during writing the file.
The problem is the newline handling of the csv module. [See this and footnote 1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.writer)

if you add `print(*stocks, sep='\n')` between line 19 ans 20 you will get following output:

```
['GOOG', 'Google, Inc.', '505.24', '0.47', '0.09']
[]
['YHOO', 'Yahoo!, Inc.', '27.38', '0.33', '1.22']
[]
['CNET', 'CNET Networks, Inc.', '8.62', '-0.13', '-1.49']
[]
```

You see... an empty list can not have 5 values to unpack

@bernie already gave you the solution in his comment.
Change line 7 to:

```
f = open('stocks.csv', 'w', newline='')
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and you're fine.